# The position of the pronoun 'me' in a sentence

Tags: pronoms-personnels

I came across this sentence in the literary short story 'Le Défi' by Philippe Sollers (1956):

> Et pourtant par ce dernier geste qui était pour elle comme pour moi la suprême tentation, j'étais sûr qu'elle me voulait défier dans mon assurance de joueur, de même que je la défiais, morte, de mon insensibilité.

My question is about the position of 'me' before 'voulait' and not after it. Why might the author have used this word order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct usage, but purely literary, and at that it is not modern; it is probably rare in modern literary texts. The meaning is exactly the same as when the pronoun is in the usual position.